# Cocapods Post_Install script error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I need to add `post_install` script to my project because of error :

> note: compiling as Swift 3.3.2, with 'ActiveLabel' built as Swift 4.1.2 (this is supported but may expose additional compiler issues)

I added suggested solution from GitHub:

```
post_install do |installer| 
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
        if target.name == 'ActiveLabel' target.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1' end end end end
```

my Podfile looks:

```
target 'Name' do
    use_frameworks!
    common_dependencies()

post_install do |installer| 
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
        if target.name == 'ActiveLabel' target.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1' end end end

end
```

I have error from console:

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
>   ...et.name == 'ActiveLabel' target.build_configurations.each do...
>   ...                               ^.

What is wrong with this syntax ? common_dependencies just init all pods.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the pod installation part here.

Your `podfile` should look like this :

```
target 'Name' do
    use_frameworks!
    common_dependencies()

    pod 'ActiveLabel'

end

post_install do |installer| 
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
    if target.name == 'ActiveLabel' target.build_configurations.each do |config| 
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1' 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this fixes your issue

```
 target 'Name' do
        use_frameworks!
        common_dependencies()
    end # this end is missing in your code

    post_install do |installer| 
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
            if target.name == 'ActiveLabel' 
                target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                    config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1' 
                end 
            end 
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution of 'ActiveLabel'. 
Use UITextView as a label, e.g:

```
class UIDataDetectorLabel: UITextView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.isEditable = false
        self.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.all;
        self.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Use this class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelDescription: UIDataDetectorLabel!
```

And

```
self.labelDescription.attributedText = "here Attributted text here which contain phone, email..."
```

[image]